# Not able to capture keys in a JSON object and map them as first row in CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I'm developing a JSON to CSV converter tool. Seeking Stack Overflow help, I was able to download a CSV file from JSON input with only values. I need the keys as the first row in the downloaded CSV file.

For instance,

JSON:

```
{"id":"1", "name": "XYZ"}
```

CSV:

```
-------------
id   | name |
-------------
1    | XYZ  | 
-------------
```

But my current output in CSV file is:

[image]

> Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavanchilukuri/4p51jyf9/) for code details.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: see this fiddle will work for you http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to add a header row to your data is to make sure that the first `json` object in your data is this:

```
var header = {"id" : "id", "name":"name", "array_list":"array_list"};
```

make sure you output this object first, then all others after it.
That will work for your particular data. If you don't know what your data might look like, you may use `Object.keys` as it will extract all keys from a json object.

```
var header = {};
var keys = Object.keys(my_json_object);

keys.forEach(k) {
    header[k] = k;
}
```

now the `header` object will contain `keys` and values as the same key name. Make sure you output it first to the CSV file.

Comment: You would also want to use the `keys` array for retrieving the object values in the correct order as object key iteration order is not guaranteed, eg `row = keys.map(k => my_json_object[k])`